# How to kill the idle connection in Postgresql.?

Tags: postgresql

I am using java servlets along with pgadmin 9.1.Problem is the connection in servlets was not closed properly so it leads to blank screen if it reaches the maximum connection.I don't want every user to extend maximum connections in pgadmin...i have used the below query in starting and end ending point of servlet but its showing error like..connection terminated due to administrator command..

```
ResultSet rs_1q=st_Query3.executeQuery("SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.procpid)FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.current_query = '<IDLE>' AND procpid <> pg_backend_pid();");
```

Comment: You should rather fix your servlet and properly close all connections. Blindly killing all sessions is an extremely terrible thing to do. Don't fight the symptoms, fix the root cause.

Answer (score 38):

Generally, as @Rahul points out, its not advisable to kill connections. But if it's your last resort, this is how to terminate idle connections:

```sql
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE datname = 'databasename'
AND pid <> pg_backend_pid()
AND state in ('idle');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think that killing a connection is an ideal solution as there may be certain connection which might be genuinely waiting for the transaction to get completed. Instead I would suggest you to set a timeout for your transacion.

However if you are desperate to kill the idle connections then you can try like this:

Use shell script and do  `"ps auxwww|grep 'idle in transaction'"`
which will return list of all "idle in
transaction." processes.
Then you can use "awk" and find of each line of output to get the 
the process id, and finally you can use a `"kill <pid>"` to each process.

Comment: Could you help me to do that thing.Need a solution for this problem.

Comment: @Priya:- You can also use the  [PgBouncer](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) which will close connections after server_idle_timeout seconds.

Comment: I dont want to use seperate script to kill the connection.I need to include the query on the servlet.Its a product,it cant be done for every user.

Comment: @Priya:- How about creating a cron job and then execute this query with that cron job: `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
    FROM pg_stat_activity
    WHERE datname = 'regress'
      AND pid <> pg_backend_pid()
      AND state = 'idle'
      AND state_change < current_timestamp - INTERVAL '10' MINUTE;` You can change the time from 10 minutes to whatever time you want.