# See progress while "iterating" over Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, plsql, pyspark, progress-bar

I wonder if there is a better way to see if Pyspark is making progress (while writing to a PL/SQL DB).
Currently the only output i see, while my code is running is:

> Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
>   Setting default log level to "WARN".
>   To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
>   19/09/17 16:33:17 WARN JdbcUtils: Requested isolation level 1 is not > supported; falling back to default isolation level 2
>   [Stage 3:=============================>                             (1 + 1) / 2]

This will stay the same from 1 minute to 1 hour depending on the dataframe size. Normally i would use progessbar2 or make a counter myself. But Spark works different and does not "iterate" the classic way, so i can not wrap the udf with the progressbar2 lib.

The Problem is, it is difficult to see if my program just runs over a large dataframe or someone has forgotten to commit to the SQL DB. Because, when Pyspark is waiting for a commit, it looks just the same. So as you may guessed, i have wasted plenty of time there.

```
df_c = df_a.withColumn("new_col", my_udf(df_b["some_col"]))
```

Would be nice to see some sort of progress from pyspark, while doing this step.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of what is your issue. It seems that your are trying to write your dataframe into a PSQL DB.
If there is already a request with a lock on your DB, you might try to kill idle requests (uncommited requests) before any spark maniplulations (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45548966/9435099) if it's relevant.
Otherwise, spark will be "slacking" forever, waiting for the DB lock to be over.

And try to avoid UDFs if you can as it kills performance on pyspark (or implement your udfs in scala)

Comment: _spark will be "slacking" forever_, yes this is exactly what i want to prevent. And i have not seen another way of telling if this is the case, other than watching the progress of pyspark. This is mostly caused by one of us who forgets to commit.

Comment: Before writing to postgresql, just either kill or rollback exisiting requests that have an idle status. Then you won't have any issues writing.
And there is no way to tell what's happening from your spark logs because everything is working properly on spark ends : it is just waiting for table locks to be removed before writing.

Answer (score 2):

You can check on the [Spark-UI](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) what your Spark cluster is currently doing. Here you can check if Spark tasks are being completed or if everything hangs. The default URL of the Spark UI is `http://<driver-node>:4040`.

If you need the data in a more structured way (for example for automated processing) you can use the Spark-UI's [REST-Interface](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, the Spark browser interface is indeed helpful, but it would be nice if PySpark tells me explicit that it is waiting for a commit from another user.

Comment: I know no way how a jdbc client (either PySpark or any other client) could tell if a database is simple busy retrieving the data or if a query is blocked by another transaction. Maybe you can try to play around with the [queryTimeout](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html#jdbc-to-other-databases)